# Disallow sharing Google Mobile Developer Services data with Google after allowed

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, google-developer-tools, google-developers-console

When creating a new app on https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=android&cntapi=gcm, I got the following to check or uncheck:

> Share your Google Mobile Developer Services data with Google to help
>   improve Google's products and services. This includes sharing with
>   Google technical support, account specialists, and anonymous data for
>   benchmarking. If you disable this option, data can still flow to other
>   Google products that are explicitly added.

Unfortunately I accidentally checked the field/allowed sharing.

How can I disable/disallow it now after project is already created? Does anybody know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is explicitly stated on which service this *data sharing* will be applied. However, just doing a quick search of that statement points to it being used for **Analytics** only.

And if you want to turn the data sharing off for Analytics, you can refer to this [help doc](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1011397?hl=en):

> **Change your data sharing settings**
>
> You need [edit permission](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2884495) to use this feature.
>
> You must customize your data sharing settings when you sign up for an Analytics account, but you can return to the Admin section of an account and change the settings any time.
>
> To change the data sharing settings:
>
> 1. [Sign in to Google Analytics](https://www.google.com/analytics/web/#home/).
> 2. Select the [Admin tab](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6132368) and navigate to the [account you want to edit](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6099198).
> 3. In the *ACCOUNT* column, click **Account Settings**.
> 4. Edit any setting and click **Save**.

If you just intend to use the project for GCM, I think it doesn't really matter if you allow it or not.

Comment: I'm not using analytics and I don't want Google to track me or my users in any way. Trying your links it always asks me to sign up for Google Analytics. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: @David The point of Data Sharing is that it is **only** for Analytics. If your only using GCM, you don't have to do anything. Stating that you don't want Google to track you in anyway, but you want to use a free service they provide is a bit weird, right?

Comment: If you still feel that you need to do something, you can always Delete the project/app from the console and then re-create/add it again.